# Big grey area in my profile image on the top banner

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, images, profile-picture

No explanation needed (I hope):

[image]

If you need explanation:

Why is it grey?

Here is the direct link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGCOn.jpg?s=32&g=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Looks like it’s a broken JPEG image attempting to render.

#### Just re-upload your main profile image to force Imgur to regenerate the 48x48 icon.

Using some creative magic (aka: Quickly interpreting how the Imgur URL is formed and what the parameters mean — I can see that the 48x48 image itself appears to be damaged when loaded by it’s direct URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGCOn.jpg?s=48&g=1

[image]

Look at this [SuperUser post on how to fix damaged JPEG images](https://superuser.com/q/192706/167207) to see an example of what JPEG image damage looks like. Note that damaged JPEG images can’t be repaired.

But since the profile image in the top bar is a *derivative* image based on your uploaded profile image, here is an idea on what you can do:

Try re-uploading your profile image and see if that fixes it.

It could be that the thumbnail generator behind the scenes at Imgur had an hiccup — or perhaps your image “lucked out” and is stored on a damaged storage area on Imgur — so re-uploading it should allow the image to be re-generated, re-saved and all clean and undamaged.

Comment: Thanks, it works now

Comment: What was the reason for this btw? Could you clarify in your answer?

Comment: @U12-F̉͋̅̾̇orward reason is bug on imgur side when they create the various image thumbnails, i.e. different size versions of the same image.